# How to use TestCafe-Cucumber Node.js project in DevOps deployments

Tags: docker, express, cucumber, devops, testcafe

I have a test framework running on my local (& git) that is based on TestCafe-Cucumber (Node.js) example: https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber & it works really well.

Now, I am trying to use this framework in the deployment (post-deployment) cycle by hosting it as a service or creating a docker container.

The framework executes through the CLI command (npm test) with few parameters.

I know the easiest way is to call the git repo directly as & when required by adding a Jenkins step, however, that is not the solution I am looking for.

So far, I have successfully built the docker image & container now runs on my localhost 8085 port as http://0.0.0.0:8085 (although I get DNS server as it's not an app - please correct me if I am wrong here)

The concern here is: How can I make it work like an app hosted so that once the deployment completes, the Jenkins/Octopus could call it as a service through the URL (http://0.0.0.0:8085) along with few parameters that the framework used to execute the test case?

I request all experts to provide a solution if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no production-ready application or service to solve this task.

However, you can use a REST framework to handle network requests and subprocesses to start test sessions. If you like Node.js, you can start with the [Express](https://expressjs.com/) framework and the [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa) module.

This way you can build a basic service that can start your tests. If you need a more flexible solution, you can take look at [gherkin-testcafe](https://github.com/kiwigrid/gherkin-testcafe#programming-interface) that provides access to [TestCafe's API](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/). You can use it instead of starting TestCafe as a subprocess since this way you will have more options to manage your test sessions.